# Square Connect API: Retrieving all items within a category

Tags: square, square-connect

I have been reading over the Square Connect API and messing around with the catalog portion.

I am unable to find how to retrieve all items and their data associated with a particular category. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

I thought it was the

```
BatchRetrieveCatalogObjects endpoint
```

I was using the category ID but it was only returning the catalog's data. I need each of the IDs of the items to retrieve their individual data.

I was looking to propagate a list of all the items and their data in one request in JSON.

**JSON data to be passed to endpoint:**

```
data = {
                "object_ids": [
                    "category id"
                ],
                "include_related_objects": True
            }
```

**My connection to the API:**

```
 category_item_endpoint =  self.connection.post('/v2/catalog/batch-retrieve', data)
```

***I am using python3 and the requests library.***

Answer (score 3):

In order to list items in a category I found it easiest to use the **/v2/catalog/search** endpoint. Simply follow the documentation on what parameters are accepted. Below are the search parameters that I used to list items by category id.

```
let sParams: JSON = [
        "object_types": [
            "ITEM"
        ],
        "include_related_objects": true,
        "include_deleted_objects": false,
        "query": [
            "exact_query": [
                "attribute_name": "category_id",
                "attribute_value": id
            ]
        ],
        "limit": 1000
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have the most luck listing your entire catalog `GET /v2/catalog/list` and then applying filtering (in this case specific `catagory_id`s ) after you get the data. Based on the documentation doing what you desire doesn't seem possible with an endpoint/query combitionation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it might be something like that

Comment: I am trying to filter the item data by the category_id key but it doesn't seem to work. Could you offer some advice or point me to a post that would help. Im still new to parsing json data.

Comment: Try looping through the results and then adding each item to a new array for each specific category.

Comment: @tristansokol isn't it possible yet to get all items by category id?